# Who was calling out to the Preacher in Pale Rider?

Tags: plot-explanation, pale-rider

Before the Preacher and Sarah "closed the door", whose voice was it calling out "Preacher" several times.

The Preacher and Sarah both heard it.  He said it was a voice from the past.

Answer (score 1):

I think the obvious answer is, **it was Stockburn**.

While we have no proof of it, the Preacher states, "*It's a voice from the past.*" This happens right after Stockburn and his Deputies come into town. We know LaHood has already told Stockburn about the Preacher. The Preacher hasn't made mention of knowing anyone else in the town, nor does anyone in the town know him. The Preacher knows who Stockburn is, so when he states the voice is from the past, it has to be someone known to him. The only new person in town is Stockburn whom the Preacher might know as a voice from the past.

Comment: It is heavily implied in the movie that Stockburn and his men were the ones who riddled the Preacher with bullets (see his scars). One interpretation of the movie is that the Preacher was a ghost all along.

Comment: @ruffdove - It was heavily implied the Preacher was Death incarnate all along. "Pale" Rider, referring to how Death rides a pale horse, which he does ride in the movie. Yes, the scars indicate someone shot him, and from Stockburn's reaction to seeing him, we can surmise he was the one who put them there. We don't know if Stockburn's Deputies were there with him when the Preacher was shot, but would have to assume they were not. There are a lot of assumptions and speculation about the movie ... one of the reasons it is still talked about today.